How can I install `neofetch` on SteamOS?
I want to run neofetch in my Konsole to see my system information on SteamOS, but neofetch isn't installed by default because I get the following:

bash: neofetch: command not found

So I searched online a bit and seems you can install it using the following command:
sudo pacman -S neofetch

But then I get an error. The error I'm getting and seeing is this:

error: failed to init transaction (unable to lock database)


error: could not lock database: Read-only file system



Is it even possible to run neofetch on SteamOS? How can I install or run neofetch on SteamOS?

EDIT:
I've made some progress on installing it. First I ran the following commands in order to enable editing on my read-only image:
sudo steamos-readonly disable
sudo pacman-key --init

And if I run sudo pacman -S neofetch now, then I get the following error:

error: neofetch: signature from "GitLab CI Package Builder ci-package-builder-1@steamos.cloud" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/neofetch-7.1.0-2-any.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).

I also tried the commands from this link:
sudo steamos-readonly disable
sudo pacman-key --init
sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux
sudo pacman -Syu
sudo steamos-readonly enable

But that results in the following:

error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.

And I also tried sudo pacman -Sy archlinux-keyring as suggested in the comments, but that results in the following error:

error: failed to synchronize all databases (unable to lock database)


could not lock database: Read-only file system suggests your operating system is not in a writable state, so the issue isn't with trying to install neofetch, I'm sure you couldn't install anything at all

@Bravo I've been able to install lots of things so far.

This has nothing to do with neofetch, it looks like you cannot install software generally. Which makes sense since SteamOS isn't a regular operating system but essentially an interface for Steam. Have you installed anything outside Steam Deck?

Ah! Have a look here: https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/671A-4453-E8D2-323C#:~:text=On%20the%20desktop%2C%20go%20to,'non%2Dsteam'%20tab.

@terdon No. I can install other things. I've installed XAMPP through the Konsole Terminal before, I've also installed lots of things from Steam and the Discover Software Center.

Please [edit] your question and include the specific commands you used to install which worked. I suspect you were installing flatpacks, not from the regular repositories (see the link above).

"I've been able to install lots of things so far" - using pacman?

@Bravo No. Not using pacman. First time using pacman.

@terdon I've edited my question with more details and progress.

@ShaunRoselt - that's important information. Now, which command produces the error: failed to commit transaction error

@Bravo I'm not 100% sure. It was either sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux or sudo pacman -Syu

Never use pacman -S <package> without pacman -Syu before. Best practice is to use pacman -Syu <package>.

have you tried this ?
pacman -Sy archlinux-keyring

@HoodadTabibi I just tried it, but it's not working. I edited my question to reflect that.
